# Get a chosen set of rows from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with thousands of rows and it keeps growing.
I want a query so I can easily display a chosen set of rows e.g:

- rows 1-50
- rows 51-100
- etc.

How can I write it?

Comment: Use LIMIT is your queries : https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LIMIT in your queries to select rows you want.

The following illustrates the LIMIT clause syntax with two arguments:

```
SELECT 
    select_list
FROM
    table_name
LIMIT [offset,] row_count;
```

In this syntax:

The offset specifies the offset of the first row to return. The offset of the first row is 0, not 1.
The row_count specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

Examples :

To select rows 1-50 :

```
    SELECT 
        select_list
    FROM
        table_name
    LIMIT 0, 50;
```

To select rows 51,100 :

```
    SELECT 
        select_list
    FROM
        table_name
    LIMIT 50,50;
```